# eledpar optional arguments in \pend

Tags: parallel, eledmac

Currently I'm typesetting a document with facing pages. From time to time the text includes some figures, that need to be shown between the numbered paragraphs. In order to the fact that it would not be necessary to have line numbers for these figures, I put them into a `\parbox` as an optional argument to the `\pend` command.

This works quite good within the document but TeX seems to have problems, if the last `\pend` also takes an optional argument. In this case I got 9 blank doublepages after the last leftsided page before the last rightsided page is printed and after that page again 9 blank doublepages appear. What is the reason for this behaviour and is there a workaround? I tried to fix it, putting the last `parbox` within a normal `\pstart \pend` section which may cause an unwanted numbering of the figure.

Here is an MWE that produces this output:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=14,BCOR=12mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[ngerman,latin]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{latin}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend[{
%Notenbeispiel
\parbox[t][4,5cm][c]{\textwidth}{\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{bsp.png}\end{center}}
}]
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\beginnumberingR
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend[{
\parbox[t][4,5cm][c]{\textwidth}{\centering\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{bsp.png}
}
}]
\endnumberingR
\end{Rightside}
\Pages
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that is a bug. Please open a github issue.

Comment: open in https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a bug, now solved. New version is updated on CTAN.